# Pandas DataFrame pivot two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have the following DataFrame `df`

| value | type |
| --- | --- |
| one | 1 |
| two | 2 |
| three | 3 |

which I want to reshape such that the desired output would look like that

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

I used

`df.pivot(columns="values", values="type")`

which gave me this:

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | nan |
| nan | 2 | nan |
| nan | nan | 3 |

How can I get around the redundancies?

Comment: ```df.T``` to transpose it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pivot the data, you can `.T`ranspose it:

```
df.set_index('value').T

Out[22]: 
value  one  two  three
type     1    2      3
```

Comment: exactly like dupe.